# Is this homebrew race, Oskin. balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, homebrew-review

> **ABI**: Intelligence +2, Strength +1
>
> **Size**. Small.
>
> **Speed**. Walking speed 20ft
>
> **Innate Spellcasting**. You can cast blindness/deafness and enlarge/reduce. Intelligence is you spellcasting ability for this. 1/day
>
> **Darkvision**. You have darkvison for 120 feet.
>
> **Sunlight Sensitivity**. You have disadvantage on attacks and wisdom (perception) checks made in direct sunlight.
>
> **Resistances/Vulnerabilities**. Resistance to psychic damage. Weakness to force damage.
>
> **Psion's Claws**. Your unarmed attacks do 1d8 psychic damage.
>
> **Languages**. Common, Undercommon, Telepathy 30ft.

If it is overpowered or underpowered please give suggestions on how I should fix/change it.

Comment: I'm unsure, do you happen to be the same user as [this RandomPerson](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/60232/randomperson) and also [Demi-Devil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/60421/demi-devil)?

Comment: If you can update this with the information asked for in [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question) and in the additional related links in the comments to that question. Until you have done so, this question should remain on hold.

Answer (score 9):

## Maybe balance is not what you want

This is a totally left-field answer, but that might be appropriate since so many of these race homebrew questions are too.

All of your homebrew races so far are very unbalanced. Do you actually *want* balanced races? You don’t have to want balance. The examples so far indicate that you’re much more interested in novel, alien races that are *not* balanced.

#### Why not stop trying to balance them?

There are many RPGs that don’t care about balancing the power of player characters, and people enjoy them just fine. Rifts, World of Synnibarr, Burning Wheel, Traveller, Hârnmaster… there is a long list of RPGs that just don’t care about balance the way D&D usually does about races and classes, and are a lot of fun.

Your race concepts would fit right into any of those game systems and function fine.

Balance just does not seem to be important, since most of the race concepts you’re aiming for are inherently imbalanced, so maybe it’s time to step back and reconsider the assumption that *your* game needs to prioritise balance ahead of your fun concepts.

Baseline D&D 5e aims for balance, but it has to work for hundreds of thousands of players around the world. Your homebrew only has to work for you.

So long as your players are enjoying their weird and wonderful PCs, and you’re not hoping to publish these for other groups who *are* wanting balance, who cares if they’re balanced?

D&D 5e is very flexible. For your home game full of dozens of strange races, maybe balance is not important.

Comment: Note that it's not *strictly* 100% clear that this is the same user

Comment: @Medix2 True! But between the name and a strong match for style, topic, and content, I think it’s a safe 99.9% chance.

Comment: Additionally, it's the same picture/profile_image, though for all I know those are randomized.Agreed it's almost assured, just felt I'd mention it

Comment: @Medix2 Oh, that’s a point. They’re actually derived from hashing the email address, so a matching Gravatar usually indicates a matching email address and very likely the same person. (They can be copied and manually set as a user image, but impersonation is rarely a worry in the context of SE.)

Comment: That isn't me. I have more rep than 1.

Comment: @RandomPerson If that’s not another unregistered account you made on another device’s login cookie, then someone has your email address and is impersonating you on RPG.se. Check your security.

Comment: @RandomPerson I’ve reposted this answer on a question that is definitely yours, since it’s addressed to you and not to this different RandomPerson using your email address, and it’s still relevant.